# Please upgrade to Billing Library version 3 or newer to publish this app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I am trying to upload app on google PlayStore but it is giving me this error.
We've detected that this app uses an unsupported version of Play Billing. Please upgrade to Billing Library version 3 or newer to publish this app. Learn more about Billing Library 3.
I am using in_app_purchase: ^0.3.4. I cannot update my whole code to latest flutter version. I need help with this

Answer (score -1):

You should upgrade to the latest `in_app_purchase` version.

In `pubspec.yaml` -

```
in_app_purchase: ^2.0.1
```

The API's used by the version you are using (0.3.4) are not supported by the play store now and thus you would need to upgrade it.

Comment: Is there way i can push my app to playstore without upgrading the package because i would need to upgrade whole app just to upgrade this package

Comment: That's not possible as these are enforced by the play store and the apis are updated to fix security vulnerabilities too. So it's much better and safer to update to the latest version

Comment: @pakalopapito did you find a resolution to this other than having to overhaul your entire app?